# Loss of all chrome bookmarks after removing gmail account

Tags: google-chrome, gmail, bookmarks

I left my old job last fall and they turned off my gmail email account. I could no longer access the account from my personal laptop which was fine but today for some reason when trying to log into one of my personal gmail accounts it kept prompting me to log into my old work account. I tried several times. So after getting frustrated I decided to remove the old work account from the list of gmail accounts. However upon doing this chrome crashed and when I reopened it I lost all of my bookmarks, history and the tabs that opened were old. Since I was not logged into my old work gmail account I don’t understand why this would happen and am wondering if there is any way to restore my bookmarks and history. The sync capability was always off since that functionality came online, turned off by the admins who controlled my old work email and not editable by the users so I’m not sure what happened. I cannot restore the computer to a previous time using system restore nor do I know if that would even work, and I did not save the bookmarks to an html file b/c I wasn’t doing anything major to the computer to warrant me losing them. Any ideas or help anyone can provide to somehow restore at least my bookmarks would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like the crash corrupted the profile.  Can you manually navigate to the profile directory and verify the bookmark file is no longer the correct size.

Comment: @Ramhound I cannot even find the bookmark file. Under my user profile directory I looked in appdata\local\google\chrome\user data for it but I don’t see anything. Is that where it should be or somewhere else?

Comment: Even if you have no bookmarks, a file for your bookmarks should exist, are you sure you are looking in the actual directory for your current chrome user profile?

Comment: I believe so but just to make sure can you verify the correct directory?

Comment: I cannot tell you what the directory of your profile is, that is something, that only exists on your system.  If you are not logging into your Google account within Chrome then it should typically by the default user profile.  However, you can as a user, name the profile so that isn't always the case.